# Create object from class name in string

Tags: c#, .net, object, reflection

I have 100 classes all having similar signature methods just their internal definition is different . I will be passing one of class name as string and I need to create object of that type and call methods . I know I can use "Activator.CreateInstance" but not sure exactly how in this case . For example lets say I have classes named Calculator1 to Calculator100 I am not sure how to cast it in second line depending on Class name string .

```
  ObjectHandle handle = Activator.CreateInstance("NameSpaceCalculator", "Calculator1");
  var Calculator = (Calculator1)handle.Unwrap();
```

Comment: Use a common interface.

Comment: You *won't* cast it. Unless these classes all share an interface, casting doesn't even make sense. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You can't do so, unless touching some kind of `dynamic`. However you can still use `Reflection` to access the created object's members without having to cast it to the desired type.

Comment: Do they all share a BaseClass or Interface?

Comment: @sa_ddam213 Yes they share a common base class , not interface .

Comment: Then you can use `var Calculator = (BassClass)handle.Unwrap();`

Comment: @sa_ddam213 I tried that and it calls methods of base class which are not implemented .

Comment: could you share some more code around what you are trying to do, perhaps there is a better way.

Comment: @Multicaster: It sounds like you need to make `virtual` or `abstract` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, but an Interface would be the better approach for this:

```
void Main()
{
    var x = CreateClass("A");
    x.Unwrap();
}

public BaseC CreateClass(string typeName)
{
    var type = Type.GetType(string.Format("MyNamespace.{0}",typeName);
    return (BaseC)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}


public class A : BaseC
{
    public override void Unwrap()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
}

public class B : BaseC
{
    public override void Unwrap()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
    }
}

public class BaseC
{
    public virtual void Unwrap()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BaseC");
    }
}


//// Here is the approach with an Interface (note that overrides and virtual declaration needed. 





void Main()
    {
        var x = CreateClass<IBase>("MyNamespace","A");
        x.Unwrap();
    }

    public T CreateClass<T>(string classNamespace, string typeName) where T : class
    {
        var type = Type.GetType(string.Format("{0}.{1}",classNamespace, typeName));
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }


    public class A : IBase
    {
        public void Unwrap()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A");
        }
    }

    public class B : IBase
    {
        public void Unwrap()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("B");
        }
    }

    public interface IBase
    {
        void Unwrap();
    }
```

Comment: I used the CreateClass approach from Saddam. It works perfectly but in your Baseclass the Method has to be virtual, so the child method is called.

Comment: I postet an approach using an Interface too. Its a lot better because you dont need overrides and virtual methods.

Answer (score 1):

You could either use a common interface with an `Unwrap()` method defined and cast to that interface, or you could use reflection to find the `Unwrap` method and call it.

Unless you're loading the assembly at runtime and can't use a compile time referenced interface in it, I'd use the first option as reflection is slow and overcomplicated for this case.

Comment: C# reflection is actually quite fast.

Comment: `UnWrap()` is part of `ObjectHandle` not his Calculator classes, I'm not to sure why there is a cast to `ObjectHandle` in the first plave

Comment: @sa_ddam213 I see now.  I still think writing a common interface will be the best solution though.

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus It depends on the definition of 'slow'. Calling may be quick, but creating the method/property/etc objects isn't fast.

Answer (score 1):

Perhap you could get the correct type first the create the instance.

```
public CalculatorBase CreateClass(string typeName)
{
    var type = Type.GetType(string.Format("NameSpaceCalculator.{0}",typeName));
    return (CalculatorBase)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it calls CalculatorBase class methods instead of that particular class .